# Why reading PDFs of Browser not as laggy than reading on a PDF reader?

Tags: browser, pdf, adobe-acrobat, foxit-reader

I have tested some free PDF reader software, from Foxit, to Adobe. But for some reason, scrolling through the pages, editing text, and adding notes. It all causes the software to freeze for a bit, and sometimes crash.

But for some reason, I suffered none of those problems when I decided to use my browser to open the PDF file. I can even add text to it and see no freezing or slow down of the program.

Is there a reason for that? Is there a PDF reader software that does not break that often?

Comment: No lag here with Adobe. Just as fast as Edge Browser.  Do you have enough memory?  Try running DISM /SFC  .  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: I would think the browser would be fast as it's not loading up as much as Adobe Acrobat Reader. Personally, I use [Sumatra PDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader) as I've found that to be the fastest and most lightweight PDF reader I could find for Windows.

Comment: Though this is not a software recommendation site, I do find free Sumatra PDF reader *very* responsive! PDF XChange editor is also fairly fast.